# Jquery Mobile Button breaks and further breaks layout

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, formatting, jquery-mobile

I'm just getting started building a mobile website using JQuery Mobile.  I'm doing a very simple design - just an image, some text, and a button that links to a similarly simple page.  I've noticed that when I click the button on the first page it breaks - it looks like it gets set to height: 100%, just before the page transitions away.

Then, when I press the back button to view the initial page, the button has moved to the very top of the screen.  I'm pretty new to Jquery Mobile so I don't really understand how they format things, which makes it very hard to debug.

To further prove to myself that I'm not crazy I copied the very basic multi-page layout directly from the [JQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/index.html#../../docs/pages/docs-pages.html).  This page works, until I change the link to a button using data-role="button".

Here's the code for my site.  Or, you can view the actual page at http://www.printartsportal.com/mobileContact

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

        <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Foo</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
                <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>
                <p>View internal page called <a data-role="button" href="#bar">bar</a></p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="bar">

        <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Bar</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
                <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>
                <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** It appears this is only happening in Chrome and the default browser on the Droid 2 Global (or, at least it *does* work in FF).  Also interesting, when using the code inspector in Chrome, highlighting the button element shows the little blue box over where it *should* be, yet the button is still at the top of the page.

**Update 1:** Things just got even weirder.  Phil Pafford posted a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9yXK/) where the code works perfectly.  I copied the exact links that fiddle was using for jquery/jqm.js/jqm.css, as well as re-copying that HTML into my file.  I'm still getting the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a result of [issue 1565](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1565) and/or [issue 1420](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1420). Both are supposed to be fixed in the latest (post a4.1) build.

My specific use case on the HTC Evo running Android 2.2 that fails with [a4.1](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/) and succeeds with [test](http://jquerymobile.com/test/)

Pages & dialogs -> Anatomy of a Page -> View boilerplate template -> Back

In your example, replace the line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>`

with

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>`

Comment: Neither of these issues look like what I'm experiencing.  In fact, running the link available in issue 1565 does not produce the error described in the post (at least in my browser).

Comment: I tried your exact example on Chrome. Changing line 5 to the following fixes the back problem: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

Comment: @jwegner Updated my answer above with description of change to make in your code

Comment: Works perfectly..  Now I just need to be ready for when "latest" moves to a real release..  and then becomes a broken beta gain :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm using your code on jsfiddle works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/S9yXK/

My suggestion would be to download jQM and use the libraries locally as maybe there is an issue with the jQM Demo site.

Note: I do see them change the JS and HTML on stuff all the time, they like to test on the demo site a lot.

Download: http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Comment: I copied and pasted the exact links that your fiddle uses into my code.  I also re-copied the exact HTML from that fiddle into min version..  Still getting the problem.  This is incredibly bizarre.

Comment: the test site is automatically replaced by the latest version from repo daily, but the `demos/1.0a4.1/` should not changed often. Did that change?

Comment: @naugtur most of the time I hit the first demo page to look at the source. It looked to have changed to beta the other day. I even tweeted jQM to ask if beta was coming, they must have made a mistake in releasing it on the demo site. They replied "Sorry for the confusion...."

Comment: At least we know there will be no more alphas ;)